# Is MODI still maintained?

Tags: c#, ms-office, ocr, modi

I'm currently looking for an OCR in C# and try :

- Tessnet2 (Tesseract)
- MODI

I saw that MODI was not present anymore in OFFICE 2010 (It was in OFFICE 2003 & 2007)

I just want to know if Microsoft did not depreciate it and if it is still maintained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page here from the Microsoft site:

[Changes in Word 2010 (for ITPros)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179199%28office.14%29.aspx)

states clearly it's deprecated since Office 2010:

> "MODI provided a common document imaging and scanning solution for
>   Office. It was also the basis of the Fax feature for Office. When MODI
>   was installed, it was the default handler for .tif, .tiff, and .mdi
>   files. **In Office 2010, MODI is fully deprecated**. This change also
>   affects the setup tree, which no longer shows the MODI Help, OCR, or
>   Indexing Service Filter nodes on the Tools menu. The Internet Fax
>   feature in Office 2010 uses the Windows Fax printer driver to generate
>   a fixed file format (TIF). MODI and all its components are deprecated
>   for 64-bit Office 2010."

Comment: Office 2007 mainstream support has ended (http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=8753) so no the product will not be supported nor updated unless you have a specific support contract with them. Errors if any would have been provided with Office Service packs. They don't provide a substitute.